# Writing into CSV loses the excel formatting.

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl

I am trying to format an excel sheet and write it into a CSV file. I am able to format the file using openpyxl, however, when I write it into a CSV file, the formatting is lost. The excel sheet has 2 values, a date "25-Sept-2017" and value of pi "3.14159265359". After formatting the excel sheet, the values in excel sheet are "2017-09-25" and "3.14". But after writing to CSV File,the values is CSV are "2017-09-25 00:00:00" and "3.14159265359"

```
import openpyxl, csv


try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("./Decimals.xlsx", data_only="True")
    sheet = wb.active

    for r in sheet.rows:
        r[0].number_format = "YYYY-MM-DD"
        r[1].number_format = "0.00"
    wb.save("Decimals.xlsx")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

with open('trialCSV.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:

    c = csv.writer(csvFile)

    for r in sheet.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

I have searched for similar issues, but I couldn't find any. I have been trying to find a solution for this for 2 days now but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote?  Seems like a reasonable question to me with sufficient information provided to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV, of course, has no notion of formatting, only data.  Excel formatting changes the display of the data without altering the underlying data itself (otherwise, for example, once you changed data from "0.000000" format to "0.000", you could never go back).

If you really want the format to "stick" you will need to manipulate the data itself (in the case of your example, by converting the date to a string formatted the way you want it, and rounding the value of pi), not the formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was some useful insight. I didn't think that way at all! Thanks again!